# Finding the Number of Primes between two numbers

Tags: java, primes

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for(int x = 2; x <=10000; x++) {
            boolean hasDivisor = false;
            for(int y = 2; y < x; y++) {
                if(x % y == 0) {
                    hasDivisor = true;
                }   
            }

            if(!hasDivisor) {
                System.out.println(a);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

So that's my code, and I want to make it so that int a increases by one every time there is a prime, but I can't figure out where to put the `a++`. Do I have to add in more code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast Algorithm to find number of primes between two numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936552/fast-algorithm-to-find-number-of-primes-between-two-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code... break statement is added and incremented a++ accordingly.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 0;
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int x = 2; x <= 10000; x++) {
        boolean hasDivisor = false;
        for (int y = 2; y < x; y++) {
            if (x % y == 0) {
                hasDivisor = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!hasDivisor) {
            a++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(a);
}
```